# how I post data to php via jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have validated a form field using jQuery. This is my validation code:

```
if ($('#name').val()) {
    if ($('#name').val().length > 60 || $('#name').val().length < 3)  { 
        errorMessage  = "Length of Your Name must be between 3 and 60.\n";
        valid = false;
    } else {
        var rege = /^[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z\s])+$/i;
        if(!rege.test($('#name').val())){ 
               errorMessage  += "Please enter Valid name.\n";
               valid = false;
        } else {
            var name = $('#name').val();
        }
    }
} else {
    errorMessage  += "please enter your name \n";
    valid = false;   
}
```

If the name field is properly filled out, the name value should be in this variable.

Name value is here - `var name = $('#name').val();`

How do I get this value to PHP? In PHP I need to validate this value again.

**UPDATE**

```
     if( !valid && errorMessage.length > 0){
          alert(errorMessage);
     } else {
      $.ajax({
            type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
            url: "demo2.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
            data: {
                myname: name,
                myaddress: address,
                myemail: email
            }
        })
```

And tried to echo name in PHP like this:

```
echo '<pre>', print_r( $_POST) . '</pre>';

if (isset($_POST['myname'])) {
    $name = $_POST['myname'];
    echo $name;
}
```

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=jquery+post

Comment: Try `$.post()` if you want to send query to PHP

Comment: Are you banned from Google ?

Comment: No I tried it using ajax. but its not working for me..

Comment: I dont know why I get down vote for this. I tried this using ajax. check my updated question.

Comment: but the problem is how to give the form data to `php` file or how to read that data in the `php` file?

Comment: @gmo please check my updated question. I can not get data to $_POST

Comment: @TNK, updated answer down... (I think you miss the name attr in the form)

Comment: I tried to debug the AJAX call using the network tab on the console. It seems pretty good. I don't know why I can't echo data to the page

Comment: TNK, I hope you find a solution... I don't know if you see the last update in my answer before it was deleted yesterday by the mod [Andrew Barber ♦](http://stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) don't really know why ¿? no comments or warning, just deleted.... Any way, good luck with your problem. PS: @andrew-barber if you see this, can you contact me an explain why you delete the answer? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should take advantage of $_GET and/or $_POST variables. Something to realize is that PHP is a server side language whereas Javascript is a client-side language. For this reason you will need to use AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

```
var name = $('#name').val();
$.post("target.php", {"name":name}, function(data) { console.debug(data); });
```

target.php:

```
<?php
$name=$_POST["name"];
$regex="/^[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z\s])+$/i";
var_dump(preg_match($regex, $name));
```